# Why jquery selector select element from old value instead of new value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, selector

Whenever I select element with jquery with selector it select element from old value instead of new value if I get value of selected element it give me new value. My code is here http://jsfiddle.net/HUdkN/3/.

Here I have use Australia value for selecting element ,even if I change value. It will select element. Why ??? could somebody explain it.

**HTML CODE**

```
    <input type="text" class="lbl" value="Australia" />
    <div id="result"></div>
    <br />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="check" id="check_btn">
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
    function check_fnc() {
        jQuery('input').removeClass('error');
       jQuery('input[value="Australia"]').each(function () {
           $(this).addClass('error');
            $('#result').html(this.value);
       });
   }

   $('#check_btn').click(function () {
      check_fnc();
   })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because an [Attribute Equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) such as `[value="Australia"]` matches the actual HTML attribute, not the current DOM property, and the `value` HTML attribute will always contain the original value of the element.

To match the current value, you can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
$("input").filter(function() {
    return this.value == "Australia";
}).each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("error");
    $("#result").html(this.value);
});
```

Comment: I got you what you are saying,Can you explain me how could I select the duplicate value input with your filter here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/HUdkN/6/

Comment: @rajesh, you would use `lbl_dup_val_arr[k]` within `filter()`, as in `jQuery("#combo_tbl_body input").filter(function() { return this.value == lbl_dup_val_arr[k]; }).addClass("error");`.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.Instead of iterating all the field.Is there any other method that I can use to directly select all the field with something value.If not than I will implement your method

Comment: @rajesh, I'm not sure I understand your last comment. `filter()` does iterate over the elements internally, but still allows to select all the input elements with a specific value "in one go".

Answer (score 0):

you use this

```
jQuery('input[value="Australia"]') 
// (") should be remove after (value=) and after Australia
```

You can use that also

```
function check_fnc() {
        jQuery('input').removeClass('error');
        //    I eddited here
        jQuery('input[value=Australia]').each(function () {
           $(this).addClass('error');
            $('#result').html(this.value);
       });
   }
```

hope this will work..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any filter for this scenario. Just **remove quotes** ie, use

```
  $("input[value=Australia]") .each(...)
```